# RPC access to a Private Blockchain Error (-32600)

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am building a private blockchain for testing. I have a droplet at digital ocean and I installed the latest geth. The blockchain has mining but only headers and there is no data for content.

I am trying to get access to the browser from the solidity browser, chrome, and finally truffle.

I am connecting as follows -

```
geth --datadir "/home/zgeth/zdata" --port 30303  --rpc --rpcaddr "104.236.58.158" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*"  console 2>console.log
```

I am using Ubunti 14.04. The error in Chrome is when I attempt http://104.236.58.158:8545/

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}
```

In browser solidity I get

```
callback contain no result Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

In truffle the command (migrate) fails as follows -

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:115:32)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:544:12)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:414:24)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:358:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

I think this is all the same error and somehow the rpc connection is not working. I have tried all kinds of variations and nothing works.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Note - since posting someone in Gitter suggested this is a memory issue. I have 512MB.

Comment: You have to provide `--networkid` of the node you would like to connect. Also do `--rpcaddr "*"`. @Trevor.

Answer (score 1):

I partly solved this. The main error was memory. The following steps solved the truffle aspect -

1. Memory upgraded to 2GB
2. unlock used when invoking geth - to prevent autolocking
3. localhost changed to the IP address ion truffle.js
4. Starting the miner in geth

This enabled to the truffle deploy to work onto the private blockchain.